# How to change the file's permission in android using chmod

Tags: android, unix, chmod, roottools

I'm using chmod command to change file's permission but it's doesn't work in my code and my device is rooted too:

```
String MyFilePath = "/data/data/MyPkgName/database/com.pocketchange.android.http.AsyncHttpRequestService.db";
CommandCapture command = new CommandCapture(0, "chmod  777 " + "\""+ MyFilePath+ "\"");
RootTools.getShell(true).add(command).waitForFinish();
```

And when it's execute, the command output is :

```
Unable to chmod /data/data/MyPkgName/databases/com.pocketchange.android.http.AsyncHttpRequestService.db: No such file or directory
```

but the file is exist, and when I use this code to change the permission of another file in the database directory its success, so what can I do now.

Comment: I don't know if the embedded quotes are required.  Can you try the command with "ls -l" on the directory and read the output to try to see if one of your assumptions may be wrong.

Comment: Is the `chmod` being called from inside a `chroot`?

Comment: I'm developing an android applications, and this code in android project.

Comment: Is there any reason why you're not using java.io.File? https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File

Answer (score 0):

Use the chmod command in the ADB shell...

```
String[] strExec = new String[] 
{ 
       "/system/bin/sh", "-c","/system/bin/chmod 777
};

try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(strExec);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Do RootTools.isAccessGiven() check first, then the system will ask for "Root" permission in the style of Dialog. After permitting the root can you successfully run the root command.
2."\""+ MyFilePath+ "\""=> MyFilePath